# nginx location regex

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm setting up nginx and I need to use the location directive to match all requests that begin with `/site1` AND end with `.php`. What regex do I use to do this?

I know I can use ^ to match the beginning of the string and $ to match the end of string. So I'm able to match the beginning of the string OR the end of the string as `^(/site)|(\.php)$`. Is there any 'and' operator so I can write something like `^(/site)&(\.php)$` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want this: `^(/site).*(\.php)$`. This means that first you match the beginning followed by "/site", then *anything any number of times*, and finally ".php" followed by the end of the string. If you don't need the captures, it would be simpler as: `^/site.*\.php$`.

Comment: for security reasons I'd put another / after /site so that /sitexxx.php is not matched.