# Rewrite Nginx URLs with Parameters (After a Question Mark)

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I have URLS in this format:

```
/wiki/index.php?title=Widget
/wiki/index.php?title=Blue
/wiki/index.php?title=Red
/wiki/index.php?title=Etc
```

I want to be able to match any URL that has the pattern "/wiki/index.php?title=" or even just "/wiki/index.php" (but so it will pick up the above URLs with the "?") and then redirect them to simply /wiki/ (all pages that match the above pattern go to the single url /wiki/)

I used to have a Mediawiki install on the /wiki/ directory with a lot of pages in the format above. However now I am running a Wordpress install and it is using the /wiki/ directory. I don't need each rewritten URL to go to a different URL (I know that is difficult as my source URLs have parameters) but right now they all 404 and so I just want to direct to them /wiki/ at least.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to go from /wiki/index.php?title=ABC to /wiki/ABC? Or just go from /wiki/inex.php?title=ABC to /wiki/?

Comment: Hi @RyanZ I would be happy with just everything that matches that format to go to /wiki/

Comment: If you have a number of URIs to redirect, you should consider using a `map`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527).

Comment: Thank you @RichardSmith - not sure how I missed that when searching. It works perfectly. I also had to add "map_hash_max_size 262144;
map_hash_bucket_size 262144;" before the map rules otherwise I got a "could not build map_hash, you should increase map_hash_bucket_size: 64" error

Comment: Actually "map_hash_bucket_size 128;" alone did the trick, "map_hash_max_size" is not required

Answer (score 2):

### Simple URL rewriting

The easiest case (rewrite all `/wiki/index.php` requests with any arguments) can be done by this config (inside your `server` block):

```
location = /wiki/index.php {
    rewrite .* /wiki/?;
}
```

The '?' sign at the end of second `rewrite` parameter is a trick to completely remove any request arguments. Without it, request `/wiki/index.php?title=Widget` will be rewrited to `/wiki/?title=Widget`.

Rewriting only requests matching `/wiki/index.php?title=...` is a more complex, I don't know how to do it without `if` construction:

```
location = /wiki/index.php {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/wiki/index\.php\?title=) {
        rewrite .* /wiki/?;
    }
}
```

If you want to generate HTTP 301 or 302 redirect instead of simple URL rewriting, you can use `redirect` (for 301 temporary redirect) or `permanent` (for 302 permanent redirect) flag at the end of `rewrite` directive parameters (see [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)).

### Rewriting URLs to individual pages

This task is not as difficult as it seems. For redirecting `/wiki/index.php?title=Widget` to `/wiki/Widget`, `/wiki/index.php?title=Blue` to `/wiki/Blue` etc. we can make use of [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive:

```
map $request_uri $uri_suffix {
    ~^/wiki/index\.php\?title=([^&]*) $1;
}

server {
    ...
    location = /wiki/index.php {
        rewrite .* /wiki/$uri_suffix?;
    }
    ...
}
```

Please note that `map` directive must be declared **outside** your `server` configuration block!

Comment: Thank you Ivan - this would work perfectly if my Blue_Widget on the old structure, was the same as the blue-widget-random on the new - unfortunately it is not. This answer did the trick for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527 but I had to add "map_hash_max_size 262144; map_hash_bucket_size 262144;" before the map rules otherwise I got a "could not build map_hash, you should increase map_hash_bucket_size: 64" error. Thank you I hope your answer is useful for people who's page URLs are otherwise staying the same.

Comment: Actually "map_hash_bucket_size 128;" alone did the trick, "map_hash_max_size" is not required

Comment: You can remove the if by using a regex location that matches strings that have q/wiki/index.php?title=` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197758/nginx-location-regex).

Comment: @RyanZ No, you can't. According to [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) (and my experience too), the matching is performed against a normalized URI without query part of request. Example you provided with your link does not use query part of request in `location` block, also see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/811912/can-nginx-location-blocks-match-a-url-query-string/811981#811981) answer.